# Ayuda con btn-group en Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, html5, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

estoy trabajando con Bootstrap 4 poseo el siguiente codigo fucional:

```
<?php $aprobar = '<form autocomplete="off" class="was-validated" method="post" action= "pedidos.php?id='.$rowid.'&user='.$rowUser.'"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success  btn-sm" name="aprobar_pago_pedido_btn">Aprobar  <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i></button> </form>';

      $rechazar = '<form autocomplete="off" class="was-validated" method="post" action= "rechazar.php?id='.$rowid.'&user='.$rowUser.'&asunto=pedido"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm  btn-block" name="rechazar_pago_pedido_btn">Rechazar  <i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></button> </form>';

      $link = '<div class="btn-group-vertical" role="group" >'. $aprobar . $rechazar . '</div>';
```

Tal cual como esta el codigo es funcional pero esteticamente los botones no son del mismo tamaño, quisiera saber como puedo lograr que los botones sean del 100% del ancho de la celda a donde se estan imprimiendo

```
<td>'.$link .'</td>
```

Comment: Podrías poner el html generado en el navegador?

Comment: es una tabla y las filas generadas estan dentro de un while

Comment: En la línea `$rechazar`  tienes declarado `btn-block` y no lo tienes en la línea `$aprobar`

Comment: Si lo declaro o lo dejo de declarar en ambas variables el comportamiento estetico sigue igual..! si quito la etiqueta `<form>` alli si los `<button>` se adaptan a mi agrupacion de botones declarado en la variable `$link` pero he buscado documentación al respecto y no logro comprender porque al quitar la etiqueta form si funciona y con la etiqueta ya no..!

Comment: Voy a revisar el codigo de `pedidos.php` porque es posible que pueda eliminar la etiqueta `<form>` asignando o cambiando las variables de `$_POST` a `$_REQUEST`